# Why does my computer have the powershell app apear on start-up

Tags: windows-10, laptop, powershell

My computer has a PowerShell app pop up. This has never happened till recently, and I have no clue what it does. It just sits there on my screen for a few minutes and nothing happens

It just doesn't respond and I end up having to end process in order to get rid of it.

My computer will also die when it's nowhere near the point of hibernation or warning me of the power level, it will just do the action of holding the power button where it doesn't do the normal shutdown process, it just stops.

Comment: Welcome. You're asking two distinct questions. Please separate them into separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have several problems.

The problem of sudden power-down may be a problem with the battery,
in the case that it is not happening when the computer is on mains power.

The problem of PowerShell coming up may be because it is defined as a Startup item.
You could download and install
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
and type `powershell` into the Filter field to find any such startup item.

If this fails, you could start `regedit` and search in the entire registry
for the string of `powershell.exe`.

If you suspect that Windows itself is in a bad shape, you could verify that
by doing
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

The before-last resort is to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is equivalent to doing again the upgrade to Windows 10 version 1903,
so take the appropriate backups.